# Cannot set DependencyProperty value through a Style

Tags: wpf, styles, dependency-properties

Experts,

I've written a custom Shape called "DimensionLine" that I'm using in various places in my UI. The shape consists of a line with an arrow at each end. It works fine but one of the dependency properties cannot be set through a style and I just can't figure out what I've done wrong.

This is the parts of the code that won't work as expected:

```
public class DimensionLine : Shape
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowsSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ArrowsSize", typeof(Size), typeof(DimensionLine),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Size(10, 10),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, 
                debug)); <-- I added this to listen for changes to the property ...

    private static void debug(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // ERROR! this code never receives value from the Style. Why?
    }

    public Size ArrowsSize
    {
        get { return (Size) GetValue(ArrowsSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ArrowsSizeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<MyXaml.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SmallDimensionLine" TargetType="{x:Type cc:DimensionLine}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DimensionLine}">
        <Setter Property="ArrowsSize" Value="4,1.5" />
    </Style>   
</MyXaml.Resources>
```

Just to make sure I added a callback listener for the dependency property metadata and debugged through a breakpoint but the value specified through the style simply wasn't written to it.

Is there something else that needs to be done for a d-property to make it adher to styles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the static constructor normally added automatically when creating a new WPF custom control

```
static DimensionLine ()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DimensionLine ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DimensionLine )));
}
```

Comment: Adding that line of code to the constructor didn't help I'm afraid. Also, it's not a CustomControl as it derives from Shape. Maybe that's why? Apparently I need to read up on this. Thanks anyway.